# Is the verb in this clause in the second position?

Tags: grammar-identification, subordinate-clause

> Vorerst muss ich noch über den Sonnenbrunnen wachen... **oder was davon übrig ist.**

because i know coordinating conjunctions are supposed to link clauses of the same type but i cant tell if the verb here is in second position or there's something else going on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's expand the second sentence:

> Vorerst muss ich noch über den Sonnenbrunnen wachen oder vorerst muss ich noch über **das** wachen, *was davon übrig ist*.

Where *was* refers to *das* and *davon* refers to *Sonnenbrunnen*.
Let's shorten it further:

> Vorerst muss ich noch über den Sonnenbrunnen wachen oder _____ über **das** ___, *was davon übrig ist*.
> Vorerst muss ich noch über den Sonnenbrunnen wachen oder _____ **das** ___, *was davon übrig ist*.
> Vorerst muss ich noch über den Sonnenbrunnen wachen oder ____ , was davon übrig ist.

So there are two verb-second main clauses, of which the second is mostly left out, and **only the new information is kept** :  "was davon übrig ist".
This is a *relative clause*, whose reference in turn was left out, too. When this is done, the relative clause is also called a **free relative clause**.

In English, I think, there is no comma necessary, but in German, the (free) relative clause needs to be separated from the clause it is embedded in with commas.

I now assumed that this sentence uses an mostly omitted main clause. Someone else may claim that that's not even the case here, and "oder" connects two adverbials, maybe.

Comment: Ah so, it is a relative **was** used after a indefinite demonstrative **das** application. Now i can see it and it make sense. But it is not correct to say "über das" right? it's darüber. you did that for explanation purposes? thanks alot

Comment: @Srmuiel No, I did it on purpose. You've got it switched up. "Darüber" would be wrong. (Dudenband 4 Nr. 861)

Comment: oh wow. i see now. cool; very helpful